# Issue with PreparedStatement while using with Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS

Tags: oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

When I am trying to use PreparedStatement with Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS, I don't know why PreparedStatement object is requiring an extra parameter. I have already googled every possible string but didn't get any response.

Below is the code that I am using for inserting a record.

```
StringBuilder headerSql = new StringBuilder();
headerSql.append("insert into TABLE_XXX(subscriber_id,company_id,stg_inv_id,inv_loc_id,count_date,count_status,count_type,creation_user,creation_date,update_user,update_date) \n");
headerSql.append("(select ?,?,XXXX_PK.NEXTVAL,?,sysdate,0,0,?,sysdate,?,sysdate from dual \n");
headerSql.append("where not exists(select 1 from TABLE_XXX where subscriber_id=? and company_id=? and inv_loc_id=? and count_status=0 and count_type=0)) \n"); 
String stgInvId=null; 
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {           
    ps = con.prepareStatement(headerSql.toString(), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    ps.setString(1,Integer.toString(IDObj.getSubscriberID()));
    ps.setString(2,Integer.toString(IDObj.getCompanyID()));
    ps.setString(3,locId);
    ps.setString(4,IDObj.getUserLogin());
    ps.setString(5,IDObj.getUserLogin());
    ps.setString(6,Integer.toString(IDObj.getSubscriberID()));
    ps.setString(7,Integer.toString(IDObj.getCompanyID()));
    ps.setString(8,locId);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
    rs.next();
    stgInvId=rs.getString("stg_inv_id");
} catch (Exception e) {                 
    System.out.println(headerSql.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();            
}
```

Below is the list of parameter that is getting bound :

[image: bound parameters]

As you can see above, I don't now from where it is adding the last parameter and what value I need to pass here. Please guide me guys.

Below is the Stacktrace :

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:330)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:287)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:742)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:212)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1159)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3284)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3367)
    at com.birchstreet.synergy.countmanagement.dao.CountManagementDAOImpl.inserStgHeader(CountManagementDAOImpl.java:325)
    at com.birchstreet.synergy.countmanagement.dao.CountManagementDAOImpl.inserStgRecord(CountManagementDAOImpl.java:280)
    at com.birchstreet.webservices.synergy.WSCountManagement.setLocationsInStartInventory(WSCountManagement.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you share the exception's exact text and stacktrace?

Comment: Which database product and JDBC driver (version) are you using? And where is the declaration and the usage of that `parameterString` variable?

Comment: Added Stacktrace, I am using Oracle JDBC Driver i.e.OJDBC6 which is returning **T4CPreparedStatement**

Comment: This has exactly nothing to do with the generated keys. The error is being thrown by `executeUpdate()`. See the stack trace.

Comment: @EJP It is related to generated keys, because when I remove that clause, insert query executes without any issue. And also the **parameterString** is having one extra value only in that case. Before downvoting any answer or question read it carefully or do some research before doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oracle `DB RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` works in that way.

1) `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` flag

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO XXX(  A, B) VALUES ( xxx_s.nextval, 'aaa')",Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);      
    ps.executeUpdate();        
    ResultSet      rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
    while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
```

Oracle doesn't know which column was auto-generated and it is returning `rowid`. `returning rowid into :?` is appended to the insert

2) List of columns.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO XXX(  A, B) VALUES ( xxx_s.nextval, 'aaa')",new String[]{"A"});        
        ps.executeUpdate();        
        ResultSet      rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
        con.close();
```

In this case we explicitly specify auto generated column. `returning a into :?` is appended to the insert

In both case you to access generated column you have to use positional access. Access by column name is not supported.

However you are trying to do `insert as select` . Statment is tranformated to

```
insert into xxxy  select * from xxxy returning rowid into :var ;
```

And this Statement is not supported by oracle db. And  exception `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended is raised`.

Comment: you are correct, when I changed my insert query to not use **select** clause it executed perfectly and your second point is also correct it is returning **rowid**. But is there any way through which I can get sequence value inserted for that row?

Comment: You can achieve this in pl sql block using `bulk collect` and `forall statements`. But this solution is not one simple query.

Comment: I manages to get this worked for me by passing column name in **prepareStatement** and 1 more thing I have done i.e. updating ojdbc6 to 11.2.0.3